# Using Javascript to Find the Pixel Color at Specific Coordinates on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible, using only Javascript (no Flash/ActiveX), to read the color of a specific pixel (i.e. x/y coordinates) on a rendered web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if canvas could render HTML then it would be possible.